# How do I navigate and select entries (for POSTing) from a matrix of values which run into several pages?

Tags: jmeter

Please could any of you help me / give suggestions on how I can achieve this. A matrix (10 rows and 12 columns) of entries run on to several pages (page by page with a link to the next page). I need to select the entries and make payment for every run. It is not a good idea to create samplers page by page so I am trying to achieve below:
{
1.  If entries found >= 20 on the first page:
a.  HTTP POST
b.  Go to step-4
2.  If entries < 20 AND Next page (link) exists:
a.  Click Next Page link (HTTP POST)
b.  Go to Step-1
3.  If entries < 20 AND Next page does not exist:
a.  Print a message
4.  Payment Page
}

Answer (score 0):

The JMeter components you will need are:

- [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) - for choosing next request depending on the number of results
- [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) - as the target for the If Controller

More information: [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I am trying to achieve this only using IF controllers